# How to multiply decimal numbers by group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, multiplication

```
 ID   |  decimalValue  
 2    |  2
 4    | 3.6 
 2    | 3.7
 2    | 10 
 4    | 3
```

Hi I grouped values of decimal numbers and used the `EXP(SUM(LOG(decimalValue)))` to be multiplied but it doesn't get any answer.
This is what I query:

```
Select ID, EXP(SUM(LOG(decimalValue))) As decimalResult 
FROM tbl_decimal 
GROUP BY ID
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
 ID   | decimalResult  
 2    | 74.0
 4    | 10.8
```

Comment: what is output of your query?

Answer (score 0):

try this !!

```
select m.id, exp(sum(log(m.decimalval)))
      from #t1 m
     where m.id in (select m2.id
                      from #t1 m2)
     group by m.id;
```

### <kbd>[sql-fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/449c9/1)</kbd>

[image]

Comment: `IN()` is actually not required!!

Comment: i also included the execution plan !!